# How do multiple users share a PipFile

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, pipenv

This article describes a multi user scenario. How does the second user update their environment with the new packages that are required? Is there a command? Is it automatic?

https://opensource.com/article/18/2/why-python-devs-should-use-pipenv

> Because Pipenv auto-documents dependencies as you install them, if Jamie and Casey had been using Pipenv, the Pipfile would have been automatically updated and included in Casey's commit. Jamie and Casey would have saved time and shipped their product faster.